# The matplotlibcpp show an error when I use subplot() in cpp

Tags: c++, matplotlib

I tried to use matplotlibcpp.h for plotting graph in c++ code. Normal graphs are plotted well. However, when I write plt::subplot(); the program throw runtime error with "Call to subplot() failed". How can solve this problem?

Below is my source code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <matplotlib.h>

namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;

using std::cout;
using std::map;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

int main() 
{
    vector<int> x1(10);
    vector<int> x2(10);
    vector<int> y1(10);
    vector<int> y2(10);

    for(int i = 0; i <10; ++i)
    {
        x1[i] = i;
        y1[i] = i;
        x2[i] = i;
        y2[i] = i*2;
    }

    plt::subplot(1,2,1); // <- error raised point
    plt::plot(x1,y1);
    plt::title("y=x");
    
    plt::subplot(1,2,2);
    plt::plot(x2,y2,"k-");
    plt::title("y=2x");

    plt::show();
}
```

The full error message is

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Call to subplot() failed.
Aborted
```

And, my compile option is

```
g++ matplotlib_test.cpp -I/usr/include/python3.8 -lpython3.8 -o matplotlib_test
```

My running environment is wsl2(windows-subsystem-linux) and ubuntu-20.04-LTS

Lastly, could you recommend what is the best way for plotting graph with c++ code?

Comment: Have you tried catching the exception and printing the message or using a debugger?

Comment: @AlanBirtles
I tried to open the header file and I found the definition of subplot().
However, the first part is just converting parameters to python tuple object.
And the next part is object check and error throwing point 

PyObject* res = PyObject_CallObject(detail::_interpreter::get().s_python_function_subplot, args);
if(!res) throw std::runtime_error("Call to subplot() failed.");

these are all.
How can I solve this?

Comment: I presume you've followed the [installation instructions](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp#installation)?

Comment: @AlanBirtles No... Because "sudo apt install python-matplolib" is not working in my laptop. And I use Python3.8. So I just download matplotlibcpp.h file and python-numpy.. Is this cause of the error?
and how I can do "sudo apt install python-matplotlib"?

Comment: I imagine a c++ library that wraps the matplotlib python library doesn't work very well without that library

Comment: Thanks! I gave up to use suplot().. But I found subplot2grid(). It's worked well. And I think this is maybe more useful than subpot for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. I found a solution to overcome these issue in the [issue area of matplotlib-cpp](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp/issues/310). I needed to change the matplotlibcpp.h from:

```
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, PyFloat_FromDouble(nrows));
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 1, PyFloat_FromDouble(ncols));
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 2, PyFloat_FromDouble(plot_number));
```

to:

```
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, PyLong_FromDouble(nrows));
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 1, PyLong_FromDouble(ncols));
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 2, PyLong_FromDouble(plot_number));
```

I don't know the consequences of changing the header file, but it solved my problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. But I finally found that if you use root user to run it or "sudo ./your_program", it would be alright
[image]

Comment: Aha.. I see. I should use 'sudo' command, if i want to use subplot(). I found the other way a few month ago that is using subplot2grid. By the way thank you very much for your answer. Because I still wondered how can fix this error.

Comment: This did not work for me unfortunately.